# Use variable in GLM quasi specification

Tags: r, expression, glm

I'm fitting a GLM to some data, using a quasi-likelihood approach (`family=quasi(...)`).

I'd like to use a variable, `p` in the variance specification, like so:

```
family = quasi(link=log, variance=mu^p)
```

This however doesn't work (it no longer recongises `mu`).

Is there any way to get R to just insert the value of p in the expression before it is evaluated, so I can use `p`instead of a number?

Here's an example that doesn't work:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(100)
y <- x^2+2*x+sin(2*pi*x) + rnorm(100)

fitModel <- function(x,y, p) {
  model <- glm(y~x, family=quasi(link=log, variance=mu^p))
  return(model)
}
fitModel(x,y,2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `variance = paste0("mu^", p)`, where p can be 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Otherwise you need to provide "a list containing components `varfun`, `validmu`, `dev.resids`, `initialize` and `name`" (see `?family`).

Comment: Ideally I'd like to use `variance = paste0("mu^", p)`this in a function that calls `glm`. This gives me an error:   'variance' "NA" is invalid: possible values are "mu(1-mu)", "mu", "mu^2", "mu^3" and "constant" - probably because p is NA at this point. Giving it a default value doesn't seem to help either. Any ideas?

Comment: Add all relevant information (including code and toy data for reproducibility) to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `family` function does fancy parsing which means the `paste0` solution suggested in the comments won't work without jumping through considerable hoops.  Also, the following function fails if any of the y values are <= 0, so I changed the example a little bit (if you do have negative response values you'll have to think about what you want to do about this ...)

```
set.seed(1)
x <- seq(2,10,length=100)
y <- x^2+2*x+sin(2*pi*x) + rnorm(100,)
```

What I did was to create a `quasi` family object, then modify its variance function on the fly.

```
pfamily <- quasi(link="log",variance="mu")
fitModel <- function(x,y, p) {
    pfamily[["variance"]] <- function(mu) mu^p
    model <- glm(y~x, family=pfamily)
    model
}

fitModel(x,y,2)
fitModel(x,y,1)
```

For what it's worth, this variant should be able to do arbitrary values of `p`, so e.g. you can draw a curve over the variance power:

```
dfun <- function(p) {
   deviance(fitModel(x,y,p))
}
pvec <- seq(0.1,3,by=0.1)
dvec <- sapply(pvec,dfun)
par(las=1,bty="l")
plot(pvec,dvec,type="b",xlab="variance power",ylab="deviance")
```

[image]